# Mix or not asp.net mvc application and Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, api, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application. I have build two layers **BLL** and **DAL** and it is ready to use.

I'd like to add a service layer: I learned about `Asp.Net Web API` and I'd like to use it to build this layer.

In the book of Adam Freeman ( Pro Asp.net MVC4) I read this

> You can freely mix regular controllers and API controllers in a project. In fact, you will usually need to if
>   you want to support HTML clients because API controllers will only return object data and will not render
>   a view.

So, I'd like to know in which cases I have to use one of this solution :

1. Using Asp.Net MVC application **and** a web API ( as a service layer)
2. Mixing the two applications in a web API application

Comment: Yes it is fine to use WebAPI controllers and normal controllers, I tend to use the WebAPI ones for AJAX calls from the client.  I would say that a "service layer" is something additional that __both__ your WebAPI controllers and your regular controllers will use in order to gain access to your domain objects.  I'm pretty sure that your regular controllers should never call upon your WebAPI controllers...

Comment: @Coulton If I understood, you are with the first alternative( separate service layer(web api))

Comment: The first option isn't technically correct because you wouldn't use WebAPI as a "service layer".  Both your WebAPI controllers and regular controllers would be used in a completely different way and __both__ could make use of a generic service layer (generic classes/methods) in order to get the data that they need to perform their duties.  If you mix the two in the same project, you aren't really mixing them, IE using one from another, they act independently of one another.  You would never call your WebAPI methods from your regular controllers - in fact, I'm not sure it's even possible.

Comment: Thanks @Coulton but why not make an asp.net mvc application and web api: In the first's views we make  ajax calls to WebAPI controllers. by this way, the structure  of the solution will be clearer and more maintenable. Besides, if I mix the two applications, did I keep the interoperability concept ie If i add a php project, can I access to the api controller's methods (services) from it???

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, but you can't call your WebAPI methods from within the controllers. WebAPI is purely intended to return data as XML or JSON as a RESTful service.  With this in mind, you need to have another layer on top of both the WebAPI and MVC application that contains the business logic for both.  It's also worth baring in mind that your WebAPI controller should only have a methods for HTTP verbs (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE).  You wouldn't create a service layer with just these methods as it would make your application very hard to maintain.

Comment: @Coulton : I have two other layers ( BLL related to a DAL layer  ) ready to use , so I will add a Web Api project ,as you suggest, which offers Html views (regular controllers) which uses Services( Web Api controllers) which finally call methods in the BLL layer. Please put a resume of your comments as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Great to hear that you already have a BL and DAL.  Yes that sounds exactly like what you should do.  Just create WebAPI controllers and methods for getting the data that you need for your views and call them through AJAX requests.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is fine to use WebAPI controllers and MVC controllers in the same project, or in separate projects, but WebAPI serves a completely separate duty.

WebAPI controllers cannot act as a "service layer" as such for your application, as it simply exposes portions of functionality as a RESTful service that can be called upon using HTTP requests (such as AJAX calls from the client).

You should use your service layer (business layer) within **both** your MVC and WebAPI controllers and only expose the data that you need through WebAPI.  It is not possible to use the WebAPI methods in place of your business layer.